# Extend sfDoctrineGuard logged-in session in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: session, symfony1, doctrine, sfdoctrineguard

Is there an easy way to extend the logged-in session length for sfDoctrineGuard in Symfony 1.4? I think it times out at 30 minutes currently but would like to make it longer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sf_root_dir/apps/<app>/config/factories.yml`:

```
user:
  class: myUser
  param:
    timeout:         1209600 # example: 2 weeks
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Came up with a solution that works for my needs: setting the "remember me" filter to true by default for certain types of logins. In this case it's a CMS that was timing out a bit too aggressively.

Resolved.